# Password validation java

Tags: java

I want to set up validation for a password field where the password entered must be at least 6 characters long and can contain letters and numbers

```
private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "^[A-Za-z0-9]{6}";
```

Then I have a validate method to validate the password.

```
  public void validate() {

if(!password.matches(PASSWORD_PATTERN)) {
        this.addFieldError("password", "Password must contain 6 characters or more");
}
```

Comment: Good work, but did you have a question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`{6}` means exactly 6 characters, use `{6,}`. I would also remove `^` from regex because it is redundant. Also note that there is `\w` predefined character class which is a shortcut for `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` if you are OK with `_` in the password. All in all it could be `"\\w{6,}"`

Comment: vote up for answering non existing question.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google revealed, that what you want to do, is somewhat common problem and people have given it try before.

For example, see http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/regex/matcher/validate-password-with-java-regular-expression-example/

They also use regex to validate password, but it is a bit more complex. It might give some nice ideas how to improve your code, once it turns out, that alphanumeric 6 symbol passwords are not enough.